# Calculadora cientifica Python

Tags: python, tkinter, math

No consigo que funcionen operaciones como sen, tan, cos, log y tal...
Esta es la funcion que llevo,

```
def operar():
operacion = entradatexto.get()

calculoscientificos =['math.tan','math.sin','math.cos','math.pi','math.log','math.log10','math.e']

for i in calculoscientificos:
    if i=='math.tan':

resultado = eval(operacion)
entradatexto.delete(0, END)
entradatexto.insert(0, resultado)
i=0
```

He importado tkinter y math, ojala alguien pueda ayudarme con eso, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que el usuario ingreso el valor 10 en la variable `x` y se nos pide calcular `log`,

```
import math

x = 10
valor = eval("math.log(x)")
print(valor)
```

En la variable `x` ponemos el valor ingresado por el usuario, y el expresión a evaluar usamos la misma variable.

La evaluación retorna el resultado de la función.

```
2.302585092994046

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Si, si eso lo se, el problema es que no consigo integrarlo en mi codigo :(