# Creación de calculadora tkinter funciones seno, coseno, tangente

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola estoy intentado crear un calculadora básica en tkinter que haga funciones básicas, pero estoy intentando hacer que resuelva seno, coseno, y tangente y me da error no se cual es el error que estoy cometiendo, lo demás funciona pero no logro hacer que funcione eso alguien que tenga alguna solución que me diga cual es mi error. lo hice en una función que lea el display y luego el valor que este dentro le saque el seno y lo transforme en radianes no se si este mal esta forma. Pd no se que mas explicar no me deja publicar el código.

```
import math
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import font
from turtle import width
from math import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Calculadora")
root.resizable(0,0)

i = 0

def get_n(n):
    global i
    display.insert(i, n)
    i+=1

def get_op(operador):
    global i
    l_op = len(operador)
    display.insert(i, operador)
    i+=l_op

def clear_d():
    display.delete(0, END)

def clear_t():
    display_s = display.get()
    if len(display_s):
        display_ns = display_s[:-1]
        clear_d() 
        display.insert(0, display_ns)
    else:
        clear_d()

def seno():
    global i
    evaluar = display.get()
    r_seno = eval(math.sin(math.radians(evaluar)))
    display.delete(0,END)
    display.insert(0,r_seno)
    i=0

def operacion():
    global i
    ecuacion = display.get()
    resultado = eval(ecuacion)
    display.delete(0,END)
    display.insert(0,resultado)
    i=0

display=Entry(root,font = ("Calibri",20))
display.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=6, sticky=W+E)
display.focus()

#Botones numericos
Button(root,text="1", command=lambda:get_n(1)).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="2", command=lambda:get_n(2)).grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="3", command=lambda:get_n(3)).grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="4", command=lambda:get_n(4)).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="5", command=lambda:get_n(5)).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="6", command=lambda:get_n(6)).grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="7", command=lambda:get_n(7)).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="8", command=lambda:get_n(8)).grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="9", command=lambda:get_n(9)).grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="0", command=lambda:get_n(0)).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

#Botones Operadores

Button(root,text="+", 
command=lambda:get_op("+")).grid(row=2,column=3,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="-", command=lambda:get_op("-")).grid(row=3,column=3,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="*", command=lambda:get_op("*")).grid(row=4,column=3,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="/", command=lambda:get_op("/")).grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="%", command=lambda:get_op("%")).grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="sin", command=lambda:seno()).grid(row=2,column=4,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="cos", command=lambda:get_op("")).grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="tan", command=lambda:get_op("")).grid(row=4,column=4,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

#Boton resultado

Button(root,text="=",command=lambda:operacion()).grid(row=5,column=3,columnspan=2 ,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="←", command=lambda:clear_t()).grid(row=2,column=5,rowspan=2,sticky=N+S+W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="AC", command=lambda:clear_d()).grid(row=4,column=5,rowspan=2 ,sticky=N+S+W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Calculadora cientifica Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/515158/calculadora-cientifica-python)

Comment: No me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

El error que te aparece te indica que el tipo del argumento que le has pasado a la función eval() es erróneo, esto se debe a que eval solo acepta argumentos de tipo str, byte o code object y el argumento que le estás pasando es de tipo float.

## Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-1-b08fd49e78c8>", line 82, in <lambda>
    Button(root,text="sin", 
command=lambda:seno()).grid(row=2,column=4,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
  File "<ipython-input-1-b08fd49e78c8>", line 41, in seno
    r_seno = eval(math.sin(math.radians(float(evaluar))))
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

## Solución:

Para arreglar eso lo único que hay que hacer es ir a la línea que nos especifica (41) y quitar la función eval ya que no nos aporta nada:

```
r_seno = math.sin(math.radians(float(evaluar)))
```

También podrías definir lo de dentro como de tipo str si tu entrada aceptara cadenas de texto:

```
r_seno = eval(str(math.sin(math.radians(float(evaluar)))))
```

También he cambiado una fila de la función get_op() ya que al seleccionar un operador de lo introducía al principio y no al final. Puedes hacer lo mismo para que haga eso al seleccionar los números porque también está mal.

```
    display.insert(END, operador)
```

Código final:

```
import math
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import font
from turtle import width
from math import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Calculadora")
root.resizable(0,0)

i = 0

def get_n(n):
    global i
    display.insert(i, n)
    i+=1

def get_op(operador):
    global i
    l_op = len(operador)
    display.insert(END, operador)
    i+=l_op

def clear_d():
    display.delete(0, END)

def clear_t():
    display_s = display.get()
    if len(display_s):
        display_ns = display_s[:-1]
        clear_d()
        display.insert(0, display_ns)
    else:
        clear_d()

def seno():
    global i
    evaluar = display.get()
    r_seno = math.sin(math.radians(float(evaluar)))
    display.delete(0,END)
    display.insert(0,r_seno)
    i=0

def operacion():
    global i
    ecuacion = display.get()
    resultado = eval(ecuacion)
    display.delete(0,END)
    display.insert(0,resultado)
    i=0

display=Entry(root,font = ("Calibri",20))
display.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=6, sticky=W+E)
display.focus()

#Botones numericos
Button(root,text="1", command=lambda:get_n(1)).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="2", command=lambda:get_n(2)).grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="3", command=lambda:get_n(3)).grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="4", command=lambda:get_n(4)).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="5", command=lambda:get_n(5)).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="6", command=lambda:get_n(6)).grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="7", command=lambda:get_n(7)).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="8", command=lambda:get_n(8)).grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="9", command=lambda:get_n(9)).grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="0", command=lambda:get_n(0)).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

#Botones Operadores
Button(root,text="+", command=lambda:get_op("+")).grid(row=2,column=3,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="-", command=lambda:get_op("-")).grid(row=3,column=3,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="*", command=lambda:get_op("*")).grid(row=4,column=3,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="/", command=lambda:get_op("/")).grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="%", command=lambda:get_op("%")).grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

Button(root,text="sin", command=lambda:seno()).grid(row=2,column=4,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="cos", command=lambda:get_op("")).grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="tan", command=lambda:get_op("")).grid(row=4,column=4,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

#Boton resultado

Button(root,text="=",command=lambda:operacion()).grid(row=5,column=3,columnspan=2 ,sticky=W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="←", command=lambda:clear_t()).grid(row=2,column=5,rowspan=2,sticky=N+S+W+E,padx=5,pady=5)
Button(root,text="AC", command=lambda:clear_d()).grid(row=4,column=5,rowspan=2 ,sticky=N+S+W+E,padx=5,pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```